# How to save data in specific tables based on category in Laravel 8

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am working on a project in Laravel which is basically a report management system. Where there will be many reports and individual information for each report I want to create a separate table for each report. The form of reporting is multi-step. In the first step, the user will select what kind of report it is, for example- if the user selects report-1 then when it saves it will be saved in a report-1 table, or if the user selects report-2 then it will be saved in the report-2 table. Please advise me on how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1:
Make two tables report_1_table and report_2_table that each have their individual columns

Step 2:
Make two separate models

Step 3:
Make 1 route that will lead to the same controller for both routes. The function this route will point to will contain the logic and will have `Request $request` as a parameter so that you can retrieve this dropdown using `$request->form_type` and make an if statement accordingly to then create an object of the correct type like `$report1 = new Report1();`